# When using autosave with black and isort in vscode, isort does not work

Tags: python, autosave, isort

I want to use autosave in Visual Studio Code and apply commonly used tools like flake8, mypy, isort, and black.

Flake8, mypy, and black work fine, but isort doesn't work at all.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

My settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": false,
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Path": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\pflake8.exe",
  "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue.
I did not know that "isort" was a default in vscode, and so I uninstalled it.

I have reinstalled "isort".
And I have modified the "settings.json" as follows:

```
{
  "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": false,
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
  },
  "isort.args": [
    "--profile",
    "black"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I uninstalled it" and "I have reinstalled 'isort'"? Are you using the isort extension or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There's now a new and **much better, faster, and more popular** alternative now:

- ruff https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff

with

- ruff VSCode extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charliermarsh.ruff

It is an extremely efficient implementation of isort, black, and other linting tools, available as a single package.

Then, just set up ruff to format your file on auto-save.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following line to your settings.json file:

`"python.sortImports.path": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\isort.exe"`

After that, save the settings.json file and restart VS Code.
Hope this answer can help you

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, "python.sortImports.path" is no longer in use. (This setting will be removed soon. Use 'isort.path' instead.)

Comment: Have you fixed your error yet?

Comment: Sure, I have solved this issue. It occurred because I had removed "isort" from the extensions. (While searching for a way to use "isort" without downloading it as an extension, I did not know that "isort" was a default in vscode, and so I uninstalled it.)

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Oh, congrats you fixed it